# Mac OS Lion - determine current space number

Tags: osx-lion, osx-spaces

Issues of Lion's spaces and their differences between SL have been discussed already in many places here, however, I was unable to find answer to my simple question - is there a way to determine the current space number?

My goal is to use GeekTool or any other method to display spaces number at my screen all the time so I know where I currently am. I have found related discussion on the [MacRumors site](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1195566) but no real answer.

I deeply miss being easily able to tell on which space I currently am.

Comment: The workaround using wallpapers is not an option?

Comment: @DanielBeck  No, as I am using the MagicWindow for dynamic wallpapers. I like the background to change and I am not keen to edit every wallpaper I use :)